# Submitting list of jobs to slurm

Tags: xargs, cluster, slurm

I have a large number of scripts that can be run as separate jobs on a computing cluster, which uses slurm. I want to select some of them, based on the contents, to submit. It's easy to identify the filenames of the jobs I want using grep, but I'm struggling to pipe those and submit them.

I thought that I could do something like this:

```
grep -l 'regex' script_folder/* | xargs sbatch
```

However, this appears to submit the all the scripts as one job, when I want each script to be its own separate job.

Comment: `grep` will look at the _contents_ of files, not at filenames. Do you want to submit based on filenames or file contents?

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm selecting based on the file contents, but the `-l` flag makes grep return the filenames.

Comment: I was momentarily confused by the bit saying "identify the filenames".

Comment: @Kusalananda Makes sense; it was somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -l 'pattern' script_folder/* | xargs -n 1 sbatch
```

`xargs` will by default read as much as can fit on one command line before executing the given utility with all the things that it has read.

With `-n 1` you limit the number of items that it passes to the utility to a single item per invocation.